# How to type in pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to ask how to I execute *pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs* as mentioned in this [website](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/what-do-i-do-when-emacs-is-frozen). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can run it from your shell, if you open an external terminal.  I would suggest instead using `pgrep -l emacs` to figure out the process ID number (pid) you want to signal, and then using `kill -SIGUSR2 <pid>` for that number, to ensure you're not doing things to unintended processes (`pkill` will signal *every* process with a name matching the pattern).